# Problem hiding element when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to hide the text with a button click, not sure how it is done:..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.HideButton').click(
      function () {
         $('#disclaimer').hide();
      }
   );
</script>
```

The body:

```
<p id="disclaimer" > DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</p>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="HideButton"  runat="server" Text="Hide" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap it in the [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), but apart from that it should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('.HideButton').click(function () {
        $('#disclaimer').hide();
    }); 
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/x38AC/) - slighty changed in order to overcome ASP dependency.) Do note, that the button may have other side-effects, too, cf. @Zootius' answer.

Comment: lol..it disappears for one second and reappears..could i use server controls with jquery at all?

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd Could it be that the button submits a form, thus reloading the page (making it seem that `#disclaimer` has been shown again)?

Comment: Try returning false from your click handler to prevent the postback. See my answer below.

Comment: what do you mean by returning false ?

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd Add the line `return false;` immediately after `$('#disclaimer').hide();`

Comment: After the `$('#disclaimer').hide();` line, insert `return false;`. This should prevent the form from doing a full postback.

Comment: `onclick` is the client click event handler. Returning `false` cancels the event. Hence, the browser cancels the ensuing post action. See this useful post: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html

Answer (score 2):

Your button should not be an asp:Button. Do this instead.

```
<input type="button" value="Hide" class="HideButton" />
```

This is because the asp:Button causes a full postback on click (check your page source - it renders as a form-submit button).

Answer (score 0):

Put it in "document.ready"

```
document.ready(function() {
     //Your code here
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$(document).ready()`? See http://think2loud.com/653-jquery-document-ready-howto/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.HideButton').click(function () {
    $('#disclaimer').hide();
  }); 
});
</script>
```

You need to tell the browser when to add the listener to the button. Usually that is done in the ready function because you want it always as soon as the page is rendered.

Comment: Actually, the page does not need to be rendered (or even entirely ready to be rendered). That's what the `.load()` handler is for. The `.ready()` handler fires "as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed." ([source](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))